# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed for bootstrap.js file- Firefox

Tags: firefox, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs7-classic

On Loading the Ext JS application in Firefox I observe XML error where bootstrap file is loaded as XML file instead of JSON.

As per my understanding content-type has to be defined in file but since bootstrap file is first to load where else to define it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRp82.png)

I tried to add mimeType in bootstrap.js file but that file is not added in GIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Due to the absence of a content type in the server's response, Firefox assumes that the response may be in XML format, given that it is an XMLHttpRequest, and therefore attempts to parse it accordingly.***

Add this script in index.html

```
<script> 
    if (navigator.userAgent.includes("Firefox")) {
        (function (open) { 
            XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, password) { 
                if (url.includes("bootstrap.json")) { 
                    this.overrideMimeType("application/json"); 
                } 
                // reapply original open method 
                open.apply(this, arguments); 
            }; 
        })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open); 
    } 
</script>
```